# MongoDB array and projection

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB and i'm having trouble doing a simple query. I have the following document structure:

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"Title" : "Title 1",
"Author" : "Author 1",
"Comments" : [ 
    {
        "Id" : "Comment1_Id",
        "User" : "User 1",
        "Content" : "Content 1"
    }, 
    {
        "Id" : "Comment2_Id",
        "User" : "User 2",
        "Content" : "Content 2"
    }, 
    {
        "Id" : "Comment3_Id",
        "User" : "User 3",
        "Content" : "Content 3"
    }, 
    {
        "Id" : "Comment4_Id",
        "User" : "User 4",
        "Content" : "Content 4"
    }, 
    {
        "Id" : "Comment5_Id",
        "User" : "User 5",
        "Content" : "Content 5"
    }
] }
```

I'm praticing and doing basic stuff. I've to find all contents posted by a particular given user. I tried the follow query:

```
db.articles.find({
    "Comments.User" : "User 5" },
  {
    "Comments.User" : 1, "Comments.Content" : 1 
  });
```

I expect

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"Comments" : [ 
    {
        "User" : "User 5",
        "Content" : "Content 5"
    }
] }
```

but i get

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"Comments" : [ 
    {
        "User" : "User 1",
        "Content" : "Content 1"
    }, 
    {
        "User" : "User 2",
        "Content" : "Content 2"
    }, 
    {
        "User" : "User 3",
        "Content" : "Content 3"
    }, 
    {
        "User" : "User 4",
        "Content" : "Content 4"
    }, 
    {
        "User" : "User 5",
        "Content" : "Content 5"
    }
] }
```

Am i missing something? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo's `find` returns the whole document that matches the query, it will not return just the element of the array that matched.

For returning just the element that matched you'll need to do an aggregation and use the unwind operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Thank you sir, i haven't thought of that. i got this query and it works :

`db.articles.aggregate( [
    { $unwind : 
        "$Comments"
    },
    { $match : {
        "Comments.User" : "User 5"
    }},
    
    { $project : {
        "Comments.Content" : 1
    }}
] )`

Comment: I'm sorry but i have an other exercice and i have no clue what to look even tho i am reading the MongoDB documentation!  
(I dont know if i need to open a new thread or if it is ok so?)

i have to find the users that commented at least 2 differents posts.

Can you help me get started? Thx

Comment: Yes, if it's not related to this question, then ask a new one. Remember to show what you have tried and explain why it does't do what you expect.